# working with Permutationed list (making pass_word list)

Tags: python

i want to create a pass_word list let's assume i have created a Permutationed list for example :

```
@@
@#
#@
##
```

and then i want to add another chars to it (for ex : a,b) **a,b is named special chars** in this code **and #@ are added chars**

so i want finally get this list :

```
ab@@ , ab@#,ab#@,ab## , ba@@, .... a@#b,...,b##a , ... , ba##
```

> Note : I don't want any special characters get duplicated for ex i
>   don't want `aa@# or bb#@` (`a,b` can't be duplicated  because they are
>   *special chars* `#or @` can be duplicated because they are *added chars* )

codes :

```
    master_list=[]
l=[]

l= list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement('@#',2)) # get me this list :[(@,@),(@,#),(#,@),(#,#)]


for i in l:
 i = i+tuple(s)  # adding special char(1 in this example) to created list
 master_list.append(i)


print (master_list) # now i have this list : [(@,@,1),(@,#,1),....(#,#,1)
```

**now if i can get all *permutation* of `master_list` my problem can be solved but i can't do that**

Comment: you dont want something like this `aa@# or bb#@` but `##` is also duplicated isnt it?

Comment: no i mean that a,b can't be duplicated #or @ can be duplicated

Comment: if a,b and in total added chars that i want to add can be duplicate problem was solved !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem , my idea : first of all i generate all posiable permutation of added chars**(#,@)** and save them to a list and then create another list and save specific chars **(a,b)** to it now we have to list just we need to merge them and in finally use `permute_unique function`

```
 def permute_unique(nums):
        perms = [[]]
        for n in nums:
            new_perm = []
            for perm in perms:
                for i in range(len(perm) + 1):
                    new_perm.append(perm[:i] + [n] + perm[i:])
                    # handle duplication
                    if i < len(perm) and perm[i] == n: break
            perms = new_perm
        return perms



   l= list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(algorithm,3))

    for i in l:
     i = i+tuple(s) # merge 
     master_list.append(i) 

print(list(permute_unique))
```

Comment: it's important to use **permute_unique** against **permutation** BIF because **permutation** will repeat  `@@1 , ##1 ` and any pass that contain duplicated word but in **permute_unique** this bug will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

You can just combine the `combinations_with_replacement` of the "added" chars with all the `permutations` of those combinations and the "special" characters:

```
>>> special = "ab"
>>> added = "@#"
>>> [''.join(p) 
     for a in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(added, 2) 
     for p in itertools.permutations(a + tuple(special))]
['@@ab',
 '@@ba',
 '@a@b',
 ...
 'a@b@',
 'ab@@',
 ...
 '#@ab',
 '#@ba',
 ...
 'ba##',
 'ba##']
```

If you want to prevent duplicates, pass the inner `permuations` through a `set`:

```
>>> [''.join(p) 
     for a in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(added, 2) 
     for p in set(itertools.permutations(a + tuple(special)))]
```

Comment: i think it's a little bug in your code : do this : `special="a"`, `added="@#` and then  ` [''.join(p) 
     for a in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(added, 2) 
     for p in itertools.permutations(a + tuple(special))] ` you will see this result : ` '@@a', '@a@', '@@a', '@a@', 'a@@', 'a@@', '@#a', '@a#', '#@a', '#a@', 'a@#', 'a#@', '##a', '#a#', '##a', '#a#', 'a##', 'a##']` as you can ses @@a  repeated , that's because you used **permutation** BIF of python , it's better to use my function to fix this a little bug

Comment: the another way is use **Set** to fix this `(set([''.join(p) 
     for a in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(a, 2) 
     for p in itertools.permutations(a + tuple(s))]))
result would be : (['@a@', 'a##', '@@a', '@a#', 'a@#', 'a@@', '@#a', 'a#@', '#a#', '#@a', '#a@', '##a'])`

Comment: @keyvanvafaee Sure, forgot about duplicates in the permutations. Just pass the result through a `set` (once is enough, though).